# regular expression for matching single characte only

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I can't get the regular expression for matching with exactly single character.

```
$strings=array('hgasdfgh','a','1','addsa');
foreach($strings as $string)
{
$result=preg_match('/[a-z]/',$string);
if($result)
echo "match";
else 
echo "no";}
```

This code match with 1st 2nd and 4th string of array. But i need it for just match with  2nd item(any character).

Comment: Why don't you give us some examples?

Comment: Why don't you just check if the string is exactly 'a' by doing an if statement like this `if ($string === 'a')` ?

Comment: @KemalKernal Because it should also match all other characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression

```
^[a-z]$
```

`^` indicates the beginning of the string and `$` the end of it.

Comment: Thank **you**, now, I have 1004 reputation and gained the privilege `create gallery chat` ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
/[a-z]/
```

So what does this mean? Match a single character from a-z.

All your array entries except the 3rd one fulfill this requirement. Therefore all match.

Now if you were to enclose your regex in anchors :

```
/^[a-z]$/
```

It would only match the beginning of the string, followed by a single letter, followed by the end of the string i.e. your second entry in the array.

Edit :

You asked for the difference of ^ inside and outside of a bracket :

When `^` is outside a bracket, alone it means the beginning of the string. If you escape it `\^` it means to match the character ^ literally.

When `^` is inside the bracket(s) such as :

`[^a-z]` it effectively negates this character class, meaning that you should match something which is NOT a character in the rance `a-z`. So this could match for example `9`, `A`, `#` etc. Finally when `^` is inside a character class but not in the first position :

`[a-z^]` it loses it's special meaning of negation and it is a literal `^` character. So the character class now matches either a single character from the range a-z or `^`.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference of ^ inside and outside the bracket?

Comment: can you help me in this case:
<pre>
$strings="ram is addsa boy";
$a="ram";
</pre>

$result=preg_match('/^'.$a.'$/',$strings);
if($result)
echo "match";
else 
echo "no";

How to represent this variable here